# How to disambiguate between async and non-async CoreData context performAndWait methods?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I am developing an app with deployment target of iOs 14. When I try to call context.performAndWait method on background CoreData context I get the following error

> "performAndWait' is only available in iOS 15.0 or newer"

the error is misleading as "performAndWait" exists since iOS 5. The problem is that swift is unable to disambiguate and figure out which variant of "performAndWait" to call. Here is my code:

```
func saveInBackground() {
    let context = storageProvider.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
    context.performAndWait {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            context.rollback()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about if you write `performAndWait { () -> Void in`? I haven't tried it but I'm thinking that might disambiguate...

Comment: I tried `let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Test"); let taskContext = container.newBackgroundContext(); taskContext.performAndWait {
 }` on app with iOS 14 as a target and not getting any warning or error. Are you getting the error with the code I posted above?